# How to move an element along a curved path based on forces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

**EDIT: I dug into the extremely well-documented source code in Decker's link ([vector movement demo](http://www.professorcloud.com/supercharged/vectors/sample02.htm)) and I'm fairly confident I can figure this out working off some of the code there. Thank you all for your help :D**

I'm working on movement for a game in javascript. Left and right arrow keys rotate an image of a spaceship while up arrow causes it to accelerate. Using the degree of rotation and the speed, I can calculate movement in terms of `x` and `y` with `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()`, but this means that the ship handles like a car. Seeing as it's supposed to be in space, I'd like to make the rotation of the ship only affect its path while accelerating and to take into account the ship's current movement.

I messed around with it a lot and tried dividing the movement into two separate forces, the current direction and speed and the desired direction, but nothing seems even close to how it should feel.

Sorry if that was confusing, here's the simplified code for the original movement:

```
function main()
{
if(keyStates[39]) // Right arrow pressed?
    ship.deg+=8; 
if(keyStates[37]) // Left arrow pressed? 
    ship.deg-=8; 
if(keyStates[38]) // Up arrow pressed?
{
    if(ship.speed<16)
        ship.speed+=1;
}
var shift=getXYshift(ship.deg,ship.speed);
function getXYshift(deg,speed)
{
    return {x:Math.round(Math.cos((90-deg)*Math.PI/180)*speed*-1), y:Math.round(Math.sin((90-deg)*Math.PI/180)*speed)};
}
setTimeout(function(){ main() }, 50);
}
```

Comment: are you using vectors at all?

Comment: are you referring to vector graphics or array-like containers?

Comment: no, all PNGs. Would vectors help somehow?

Comment: sorry I meant are you using vectors to keep track of the ships velocity and direction?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The ship's velocity and direction are stored in the ship object.

Comment: Comment on [that example you found](http://www.professorcloud.com/supercharged/vectors/sample02.htm): Good example how you should *not* do collision: Putting more and more energy into the [elastic system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) through accelerating the ship leads to uncontrollable behaviour :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one Vector to keep track of the ships speed and direction and alter the direction of that vector when the up arrow is pressed by checking the angle of a second Vector used to keep track of the ships current angle.

I recommend getting this book [Supercharged Javascript Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449393632) which explains in detail the use of vectors and much more.

You can also view the source code for one of the books examples here [at the authors website](http://www.professorcloud.com/supercharged/vectors/sample02.htm) which has a vector handling object that could prove useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a mathematical concept known as a "vector" for your movement. A vector is simply a force and a direction. This vector will be applied to the X,Y coordinate of your ship (ignoring its direction) every frame when determining where to draw the ship. When you accelerate you will use the direction the ship is facing and a constant value assigned to acceleration to form a vector that can be applied to your movement vector for calculating its effect on velocity.

Here is a quick introduction to vectors: http://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/v/introduction-to-vectors-and-scalars , after watching the video you should have a good idea about what need to be looking for. From there Google should be your friend.

**EDIT:** Above when I said: "you will use the direction the ship is facing and a constant value assigned to acceleration to form a vector that can be applied to your movement vector for calculating its effect on velocity" I was referring to vector algebra. If you decide to use vectors to solve your problem, you will need to use the concept of vector addition to accelerate. When you press the arrow key, you will generate a vector of magnitude m (where m can be any real number indicating how fast you want to accelerate) and a direction d (more than likely this value will correspond with the direction the ship is facing). You will then add this new vector to the ships current vector to get the ships new vector after the acceleration for the current frame is applied. You can read more here: http://emweb.unl.edu/Math/mathweb/vectors/vectors.html

Cheers and happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

Based on my low physical knowledge:

The ship has a speed with a direction. This can be expressed as a vector from your space, like x pixels on the X-axis, y pixels on the Y-axis (and maybe more dimensions) per second.

Then it has a rotation speed, like α degrees counterclockwise per second.

To compute the travel of your ship for a second, just add the speed vector to the coordinates. And add the rotation to the current orientation.

To change the speed vector based on rotation and acceleration, you would build a vector with a length relating to the acceleration, in the direction of the current orientation. Then add the acceleration vector to the speed vector.

Pseudo code:

```
ship = {
   coordinates: [0, 0], // space units
   orientation: 0, // radiant
   speed: [0, 0], // space units / time frame
   rotation: 0 // radiant / time fram
}
function animatestep {
   coordinates[0] += speed[0];
   coordinates[1] += speed[1];
   orientation += rotation;
}
onaccelerate = function {
   speed[0] += cos(orientation) * acceleration;
   speed[1] += sin(orientation) * acceleration;
}
onleft = function {
   rotation++;
}
onright = function {
   rotation--;
}
```

Note that this makes the space ship really behave like a space ship, because rotation might be difficult to stop. Instead of using a rotation speed, you might need to allow to set the orientation of the ship step-by-step :-) You might also set limits on rotation and acceleration (otherwise the ship bursts) and use a maximum velocity (like the speed of light, including [different speed addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_theory_of_relativity)).

Comment: That was very helpful Bergi, and thanks Crackers for the link on vectors. I understand most of this, but can you explain further what you mean about 'building a vector with a length relating to the acceleration, in the direction of the current orientation' and adding it to the speed? Thank you so much.

Comment: That acceleration you add to the speed is again a vector. It is directed in the current ship orientation (you see `sin`/`cos` in the `onaccelerate` function?), and multiplied by the force of acceleration. You could think of this as a vector in [polar notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), with an azimuth of `orient` and a radius of `accel`

Answer (score 1):

Do you use getXYshift after a right/left arrow press? You should only use it when the up arrow is pressed. This way your ship will rotate without accelerating in any direction. Only change your velocity when the up arrow key is pressed and decelerate when it isn't. Don't change the velocity with the right/left keys, use them to change the rotation of your ship.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear with the code. The keyState checks are in a loop and getXYshift is called every iteration because the ship is still moving regardless of the up arrow being pressed. I updated the code to show this.